I am getting an "invalid user or password" error while testing a API
I am trying to built an log in API but getting a a "invalid user or password" error while testing. I have checked the database and user and password is correct and exists and correct.
Here is the whole code:-
models.py:
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin

class Address(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ('office', 'Office'),
        ('factory', 'Factory')
    ]
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    addressLine1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    addressLine2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    addressLine3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email field must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(email, username, password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)  # Add this line for the password field
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business_category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number_of_employees = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    usage_description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    otp = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

views.py:
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from .serializers import UserRegistrationSerializer, OTPVerificationSerializer, ForgotPasswordSerializer
from .utils import generate_otp, send_otp_email
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from .serializers import UserSerializer, ForgotPasswordSerializer, LoginSerializer, OTPVerificationSerializer
# from rest_framework.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def register(request):
    serializer = UserRegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        # Generate OTP
        otp = generate_otp()
        # Save OTP to the user instance
        user = User.objects.get(email=request.data['email'])
        user.otp = otp
        user.save()
        # Send OTP via email
        send_otp_email(request.data['email'], otp)
        return Response({'message': 'User registered successfully. OTP sent to your email.'})
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def verify_otp(request):
    serializer = OTPVerificationSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        email = serializer.validated_data['email']
        otp_from_user = serializer.validated_data['otp']
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'message': 'User does not exist'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        if otp_from_user == user.otp:
            user.is_verified = True
            user.save()
            return Response({'message': 'OTP verified successfully'})
        else:
            return Response({'message': 'OTP verification failed'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@csrf_exempt
def login(request):
    email = request.data.get('email')
    password = request.data.get('password')
    print(f'Email: {email}')  # Print the email
    print(f'Password: {password}')  # Print the password
    # user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
    # print(f'User: {user}')  # Print the user object
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({'message': 'User does not exist'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    
    if user.check_password(password):
        # Assuming you want to login only if user is verified
        if user.is_verified:
            # Generate token
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            # Return token and success message
            return Response({'token': token.key, 'message': 'User logged in successfully'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({'message': 'User is not verified. Please verify your account first.'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    else:
        return Response({'message': 'Invalid email or password'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)



@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def forgot_password(request):
    serializer = ForgotPasswordSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        email = serializer.validated_data['email']
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'message': 'User does not exist'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        # Generate OTP
        otp = generate_otp()
        # Save OTP to the user instance
        user.otp = otp
        user.save()
        # Send OTP via email
        send_otp_email(email, otp)
        return Response({'message': 'Password reset email sent'})
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

serializers.py:
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User, Address

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = '__all__'

class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        address_data = validated_data.pop('address')
        address = Address.objects.create(**address_data)
        user = User.objects.create(address=address, **validated_data)
        return user

class OTPVerificationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    otp = serializers.CharField(max_length=6)

class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)  # Hide password in response

    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = attrs.get('email')
        password = attrs.get('password')

        if email and password:
            user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
            if user:
                # Perform your login validation here, e.g., check password
                if user.check_password(password):
                    return attrs
                else:
                    raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect email or password.")
            else:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("User not found.")
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Email and password are required fields.")

class ForgotPasswordSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()

utils.py:
import random
import string
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings

def generate_otp(length=6):
    return ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=length))

def send_otp_email(email, otp):
    subject = 'OTP Verification'
    message = f'Your OTP for verification is: {otp}'
    sender_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    send_mail(subject, message, sender_email, [email])

User registration is successful, OTP verification is also successful but getting the error while testing the log in API although the email and password exists in the database and I've manually checked that.
And here is the error:
{
  "message": "Invalid email or password"
}

How do I solve this issue ?
I have checked database and user exists and I also printed user and password in terminal and the user and password are correct but I still keep getting the error.

You should add your Auth User model. authenticate invokes authentication against your Auth User model.

Your check_password() fails. Please note that passwords are usually stored as a hash which is different from the actual password.

Also check_password runs a password validation check against a hashed password stored in the database. If your password is not stored as a hash value, that invocation will fail. Hence it is important to share your Auth User model.

With more info, I will write an answer for you.

@ChukwujiobiCanon how to and where to add Auth User Model

Please dont upload your entire code base in a Single question. Ask for a more specific answer

You already do —User. But you don’t hash password on saving a User instance.

@ChukwujiobiCanon how to hash a password while saving a user instance

For posterity, when one uses a custom Auth User model, one has to handle most by oneself. Amongst this, one has to register the model in the admin site, one has to handle password hashing for secure password storage, one has to define a custom model form e.t.c.
In the case of password hashing, if you do not hash password, it will be stored in plain text. Hence it is important to hash password before storage for security reasons. There are many hashing algorithms Django offers which you can choose from and they each have their pros and cons. See "Password management in Django". [django-docs]
The best place to hash password is on saving a User instance. Override the save method of the model and perform hashing on the password field of the instance.
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    •••Rest of code•••
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.password = make_password(self.password)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
make_password() [django-docs] uses the first entry of PASSWORD_HASHERS setting to turn a plain password text to a cipher.
Now your invocation of check_password() [django-docs] will behave as expected. It will correctly compare the plain password text to the hashed password in the database.
